# Colors associated to parts of a 3D distribution of points

Tags: list-manipulation, random, distributions, generative-art

Suppose we have a long list of random points (in Cartesian coordinates) in 3D space.

```
coords := ...;
```

Until now, I was associating colors in a radial way, from the center to the edge of the distribution :

```
SpriteColor = Blend[{InternalColor, MiddleColor, MiddleColor2, ExternalColor}, #]&;
```

I'm now wondering how could we associate the colors by random "small patches" over the distribution of points, with smooth blending between the patches.  What I mean by "patches" is this:  some red here, blending to blue there, red again in another random part, blending to green over there, etc.

The random distribution of colors should need the number of "patches" as input, and a set of colors (as in my example above, for the radial distribution).

Any suggestion about how to do this?

For a crude example, here's a version with the radial colors (easy to do with the above color directive) :
[image: my crude example]

And here's a **very crude** sketch (handmade) of what I would like to do, instead of a radial coloring.  The patches should be randomly placed:
[image: sketch]

Notice that I'm working with ***Mathematica 7***.

**EDIT :**

Here's a full working example for a radial color distribution on a cube of points. I would like to distribute the colors on, say, 7 spots randomly distributed on the whole distribution of points, instead of an unique radial blend.

```
InternalColor := RGBColor[0.95, 0.0, 0.0, 0.99]; (* color at the center of the distribution *)
MiddleColor := RGBColor[0.0, 0.95, 0.0, 0.9]; (* color of transition to the exterior part *)
ExternalColor := RGBColor[0.0, 0.0, 0.95, 0.9]; (* color of the exterior part *)

testCoords = RandomReal[{-1, 1},{10000, 3}];

radialColors = Blend[{InternalColor, MiddleColor, ExternalColor2}, #] &;

Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[testCoords, VertexColors ->(radialColors[Norm[#]] & /@ testCoords)]}, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 800, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

Output:

[image: expected output]

Comment: Can you at least include a picture illustrating what you want to see from answers?

Comment: I've edited the question.  Notice that the second picture is **very** crude (it was done in less than 1min, by hand, and I'm not good with my pictures editor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for all the edits! I hope this is now closer to what you expected.

**BASIC CASE**

First, we generate some coords in the unit cube:

```
coords = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 3}];
```

Next, I create an input vector (deterministic):

```
inputs = {{Yellow, {1, 0, 0}, 1}, {Green, {1, 1, 1}, 
1}, {Blue, {-1, 0, 0}, 1}, {Red, {0, 0, 0}, 0.75}};
```

of the following form: `{"Color","Center","Radius"}`. Note that I chose this as a **non-random** vector, to get a slightly better picture of what happens. Also note that the colored patches will be spheres. For now I couldn't find any idea on how to make that randomly shaped.

You can then randomize the `inputs` vector to get random colors/centers/radii.

Based on the comments, I now fixed a `baseCol` and an "aggressiveness"-var that specifies how "aggressively" that base color eats into the patches. Play around and see.

For the next image, I chose:

```
aggr = 0.5;
```

and

```
baseCol = LightGray;
```

and the adjusted code:

```
Graphics3D[{Blend[Prepend[inputs[[All, 1]], baseCol], 
 With[{fun = 
    Function[x, 
      Max[0, 1 - 1/#[[3]] Norm[x - #[[2]]]] & /@ inputs][#]}, 
  Flatten@{Max[0, aggr - Total@fun], fun}]], Point@#} & /@ coords]
```

[image]

**OPACITY**:

say you want opacity as well, one could e.g. do something of the following:

```
baseCol = Append[LightGray, 0.25];
```

(rather opaque)

and

```
 inputs = {{Append[Yellow, 0.9], {1, 0, 0}, 
 1}, {Append[Green, 0.9], {1, 1, 1}, 
 1}, {Append[Blue, 0.7], {-1, 0, 0}, 
 1}, {Append[Red, 0.9], {0, 0, 0}, 0.75}};
```

where I assumed that you already have your colors in that format, so excuse the syntax.

Then we get:

[image]

**Your Layout**

Based on your edit: If you want the coloring function "standalone", you could do:

```
myCol = {Blend[Prepend[inputs[[All, 1]], baseCol], 
 With[{fun = 
    Function[x, 
      Max[0, 1 - 1/#[[3]] Norm[x - #[[2]]]] & /@ inputs][#]}, 
  Flatten@{Max[0, aggr - Total@fun], fun}]]} &;
```

and then (in your layout):

```
Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[4], 
 Point[coords, VertexColors -> (myCol /@ coords)]}, Boxed -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

to get:

[image]

NOTE: your `SpriteColor` function takes a real as input (as you only need the `Norm` to do the coloring), where `myCol` takes `{x,y,z}`

Comment: That is nice.  But the colors doesn't blend smoothly.  See the yellow and black dots.  Their delimitation is very sharp and clear.

Comment: ah, you want to blend to "base" color too? I figured you just want to blend between the patches, see red - yellow. Let me think.

Comment: Also, I'm yet unable to apply your color directive to my list of points.  I need the color function to define a list of 4 numbers (RGB and opacity), as much multiplets that there are points in the distribution.  I'll edit the question to give a full example with radial colors.

Comment: That looks better.  Actually, I could forget about the random distribution of the colors.  I'll see if I can apply this to my project.

Comment: to use opacity as well, one might just append that to the colors in `inputs` and `baseCol`. Will edit in a sec

Comment: @Cham: added 4th argument in RGB as well, I used `Append` in a way that makes it easier to spot. (Alternatively, one could use it as another argument in the `inputs` vector and do the appending in the function. But as I guess you have your colors in that format, it might be easier like that. Sorry for all the edits :)

Comment: It's working right now.  I'll have to adapt it to my project and see...

Comment: How do you separate the blend directive from the Graphics3D command ?  I need it to be an independant function, so the color directive could be exported into an ASCII file.  See for example my ** SpriteColor** function, in my question.

Comment: I just added another section, I hope this takes care of it. Good luck, I gotta run now!

Comment: It's working !  And it's MUCH faster too !  Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 4):

If one processes the list of points as a block, some speed-up can be realized from built-in optimization of some functions.  This problem also amenable to compilation.

Some initial data:

```
testCoords = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 3}];
colorCtrs = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {7, 3}];
baseColors = Table[ColorConvert[Hue[i/7., 1, 1, 1.], "RGBColor"], {i, 7}];
```

A convenient function for plotting the colored point cloud:

```
spritePlot[spriteColorFn_, points_] := Graphics3D[{
   PointSize[0.0067], 
   Point[points, VertexColors -> spriteColorFn[points]]}, 
  Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 180]
```

Given a list of `colors` (as rgb and corresponding `centers` (points) for the colors, `spriteCF` computes the color or colors for the `point` or `points` (resp.) based on how close each point is to each center and on the decay `rate`.  The colors of each center are averaged together with translucent gray, `RGBColor[0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022]`, each color being weight by `Exp[-rate * dist^2]`, where `dist` is the distance to the color center, and gray receiving a constant weight of `0.08`.  The parameters `0.022` and `0.08` were chosen by trial.

The OP indicated a need for a function to handle a single point, so two interfaces are given to handle a single point and a list of points.  As implied above, it is efficient on lists of points.

```
spriteCF[colors_, centers_, point_?VectorQ, rate_: 1.] := 
  First@cf[colors, centers, {point}, rate];
spriteCF[colors_, centers_, points_?MatrixQ, rate_: 1.] := 
  RGBColor @@@ compSCF[colors, centers, points, rate];
compSCF = 
  Compile[{{colors, _Real, 2}, {centers, _Real, 2}, {points, _Real, 
     2}, {rate, _Real}},
   Module[{weights},
    weights = 
     Exp@Map[-rate #.# &, (* wt = Exp[-rate * dist^2] *)
       Transpose[Table[points, {Length[centers]}]] - 
        Table[centers, {Length[points]}], {2}];
    ((0.022 + MapThread[ (* The 0.022 averages in some gray and lower opacity *)
               Dot,      (* and 0.08 determines the threshhold when gray is dominant *)
               {weights, Table[colors, {Length[points]}]}]) /
      (0.08 + Total[Transpose@weights]))
    ], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

The higher the decay `rate`, the smaller the colored ball around each center.  Below are plots for `rate = 2, 6, 10`:

```
Row@Table[spritePlot[spriteCF[baseColors, colorCtrs, #, r] &, testCoords], {r, 2, 10, 4}]
```

[image: Three point clouds with different decay rates]